# writing a function alternate to String.prototype.replace()

Tags: javascript

I want to write a **function** to get a string and then replace the given value to a given character
it is like:

```
function(str, charToChange, charToReplace){}
```

I used the `String.prototype.replace()`

Is there any other way? (like using a loop)
built-in functions like `replace`, `join`, `split`, ... should not be used

```
var myStr = 't|e|s|t|1';
var newStr = myStr.replace(/\|/g, '');
console.log(newStr); //test1


var myStr = 'B1C1D1E1F';
var newStr = myStr.replace(/1/g, '');
console.log(newStr); //BCDEF

var myStr = 'Test*Num*One';
var newStr = myStr.replace(/\*/g, '');
console.log(newStr); //
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
    replaceString = function (str, charToChange, charToReplace) {
     let newStr = '';
     for (let i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
      if (str[i] == charToChange) {
       if (charToReplace != '') {
        newStr += charToReplace;
                }
            }
      else {
       newStr += str[i];
            }
        }
     return newStr;
    }

    var myStr = 't|e|s|t|1';
    var newStr = replaceString(myStr, '|', '');
    console.log(newStr); //test1


    myStr = 'B1C1D1E1F';
    newStr = replaceString(myStr, '1', '');
    console.log(newStr); //BCDEF

    myStr = 'Test*Num*One';
    newStr = replaceString(myStr, '*', '');
    console.log(newStr); //
```

Comment: That is the confusing part. OP is saying no build in function can be used, but he has not clarified if `length` can be used

Comment: Yeah I was a little confused by that too, @brk

Answer (score 2):

Using `for..in` loop

```js
function a(string, charToChange, charToReplace) {
  var str = '';
  for (let i in string)
    string[i] != charToChange ? str += string[i] : str += charToReplace;
  console.log(str)
}

a('Test*Num*One', '*', '')
a('t|e|s|t|1','|','')
a('B1C1D1E1F','1','')
```

Use `split` and `join` to achieve the same

```js
var myStr = 't|e|s|t|1';
var newStr = myStr.split(/\|/g).join('');
console.log(newStr); //test1


var myStr = 'B1C1D1E1F';
var newStr = myStr.split(/1/g).join('');
console.log(newStr); //BCDEF

var myStr = 'Test*Num*One';
var newStr = myStr.split(/\*/g).join('');
console.log(newStr); //
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a custom function and split the string, which will create an array , then use `filter` to filter out those characters which are not required.`filter` will create another and use `join` to join elements of the new array

```js
function replaceChar(char, str) {
  let k = '';
  Array.from(str).forEach(function(item) {
    if (item !== char) {
      k += item
    }
  })
  return k;
}
console.log(replaceChar('*', 'Test*Num*One'));
console.log(replaceChar('|', 't|e|s|t|1'));
console.log(replaceChar('1', 'B1C1D1E1F'));
```

Comment: no built-in functions (split, join, ...)should be used